# TBLFM - :: (two colons) - what does it mean?

Tags: org-mode

here my table's formula:

```
#+TBLFM: $6=date(<$3>)-date(<$2>) :: $7=60*60*24*$6;T :: @>$6 = vsum(@I..@II) :: @>$7 = vsum(@I..@II);T
```

What two colons mean " **::** " ?

Answer (score 1):

Two colons in a `TBLFM` line separate two different formulas, which are written in the same `TBLFM` line. 
Why would you want to write two formulas on the same line? -> so you can easily reevaluate the formulas with a single `C-c C-c`.

Have a look at a tutorial:
https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-intro.html